# How can I get the name of a Visual Basic control given its HWND?

Tags: vb6, automation

I'm working on a little macro record/replay tool which can automate a few very old Visual Basic 6 GUIs we have. To do so, I'm identifying the controls by their name (the value of the `name` property of a control, that is).

One part of this tool needs to determine the name of a control given its HWND. For newer Visual Basic applications which were done using VB.NET, I can use the [WM_GETCONTROLNAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996405.aspx) window message. This works nicely.

However, this message is not understood by older windows. Is there any way to do this for controls of Visual Basic 6 applications? A solution which does not require being in the process of the GUI would be preferrable, but if I had a solution which only works inside the GUI process then that would be acceptable as well (since I can do the injection myself).

**UPDATE:** One thing I just tried, this moderate success: I used the [AccessibleObjectFromWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317978(VS.85).aspx) to check for implementations of the [IAccessible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318466(VS.85).aspx) interface of the object which shows the given HWND. In case I get an implementation (it seems that many [all?] Visual Basic controls implement this interface), I use the [accName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318483(VS.85).aspx) property to read out the "accessible name". Sometimes this does yield a useful string, but usually it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way would be getting inside the process and obtaining a pointer to the `Form` object, yet I have no idea how to do it from outside.

Is it possible you add support for the `WM_GETCONTROLNAME` to those older applications?

Or maybe, you could identify the controls by some other, natively-available properties?

Other that that, as Raymond is saying, [there isn't much you can do](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100329-00/?p=14473).

Comment: Those are all godd suggestions, thanks! Right now it really seems that I need to hook into the process (I can do that) and then access the Form object directly. I'm not sure how to do that, but have done something similar a few months ago already, so it might work out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the vb6 apps? if so in each form load event you could iterate me.controls and use the `SetProp(ctrl.hwnd, "MYNAME:" & ctrl.name, 0)` api to add the name to the window's own property list, then in your other app you can `EnumProps(ctrl_HWND)` looking for the one that begins with `MYNAME:` and parse out the value.

Comment: Pretty creative idea! However - no, I can't modify the applications. I believe I don't even have the source code for them accessible. Somebody told me that there's a tool which can be used to read out the Visual Basic names for a given GUI and apparently some GUI testing tools can do this, too - so it must be possible, somehow.