# How can I get properties of a VB6 Control given just it's hWnd?

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 program and have a callback that has the hWnd of the control. I want to find out which control that is.

So I'm trying to find properties ( control.name, etc.) using just the hWnd.
There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365031/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-a-visual-basic-control-given-its-hwnd) but it's limited by retrieving this info from another program. I'm hoping that since this is all within the same vb6 program there is a simpler solution.

Comment: I've not got a VB6 IDE any more to have a go at this.  Recommended reading is Matt Curland's 'Advanced Visual Basic 6' which has a lot of detail on subclassing Windows safely.

Comment: The "built in" way would be to for/each the parent forms controls collection  (and any containers) and look at each individual control, determine if it has a hwnd property and see if it matches your value.

Comment: If you set up the subclassing yourself then you can use SetProp on the hwnd to store a pointer to the control then resolve that back to the control instance variable in your WndProc.